# How do I store several values in byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, bytearrayoutputstream

So I am currently trying to save and load Data for my Java application. Now i am trying to save all my data in one big `byte[]` which I can than write to a file using Base64. I've seen something like this before, where you can do `writeString(String s)` to write a String to a `byte[]` and use `readString()` to read the String from the `byte[]`. I was wondering how exactly this works; How can I write *several* values to the `byte[]` and know when one Value ends and another begins. With Integers it would be easy, because they have a fixed size, but Strings are dynamic, so how can I see when the String in the `byte[]` ends?

I already managed to write data to a `byte[]` using the `ByteBufferOutputStream` and now I need to know how I can discriminate the different values. Could I for example insert a `0x0`-byte where the String's bytes end to know when to stop reading the `byte[]`?

Comment: Either a 0x00 to indicate end of string or you could store the length of the string first then then data bytes after that.

Comment: That sounds like a good Idea! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: You could also use `ObjectOutputStream` to write bytes to an array/buffer, and let that Java class do the marshaling for you.

Comment: @JJF if you post your comment as an answer I can mark this as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a 0x00 to indicate end of string or you could store the length of the string first then then data bytes after that.